# get a json file in local (jquerymobile & phonegap)

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, localhost, getjson

I would like to know if it's possible to get a json file which is in local?
If yes, how?

I've tried

```
function test() {
 $.getJSON("c\\file.json", function(json) {
   console.log(json); 
 });
 }
```

and

```
    function test() {
      $.getJSON("http://localhost/file.json", function(json) {
       console.log(json); 
      });
    }
```

I am using wampserver.

Answer (score 3):

I have just found a way to load a JSON file stored locally without using the [Phonegap File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html). It's really easy and worked for me with Cordova 2.7.0 (I have only tested it on an Android device) : I fake a JSONP request using [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). So your ajax call looks like that :

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data.json',
            crossDomain: true,
            jsonpCallback: 'cb',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
        })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); alert('Failed to load data.'); })
            .done(function (data) {
                app.data = data;
        });
```

The crossDomain parameter is to force a crossDomain request (JSONP) on the same domain. I also force the callback function name to cb. Also notice that JSONP requests do not support synchronous operation.

Then you have to wrap your JSON data with your callback function like that :

```
cb(
    {
        "title": "the title,
        "id": 1
    }
);
```

It's a little tricky and probably not a very good practice. What do you think about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the loopback address, instead of localhost, like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/file.json", function(json) {
```

Comment: I tried `file:///C:/file.json` AND `file://localhost/file.json` AND `http://127.0.0.1/file.json`
But nothing works.

Comment: Make sure you have your file.json at the root of your document_root (i.e. the root folder where your web is served from)

Comment: My file is in the right folder. I have an error in the log that I do not understand `unknown chromium error: -6 `

Answer (score 0):

For the better programming, use the relative path to load the JSON file.

```
 $.getJSON("file.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); 
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the file format:

`file:///C:/folderA/test.html`

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fileurl.html

Comment: Do you, at least, know if it's possible do get data from a JSON file which located in local ?